# Target a specific part of a string based on order

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to fetch a number from meta tags - but unsure how to targets the specific part of the string. I want to fetch the number in the string - 0888462709866. How do I fetch it - I need to go by its place in the string?

Problem is that it can sometimes be no string - as per the second example below. It dies keep the comma so the order should e the same anyhow?

Script:

```
ccs_cc_args.push(['EAN_CODE', $("meta[name='description']").attr('content')]);
console.log(ccs_cc_args);
```

With number:

```
<meta name="description" lang="nl" content="MacBook 12&quot; 16E M5-6Y54/8GB/512SSD/Space Grey CM5 1.2GHz/HD Graphics 515/US Int. keyboard, MLH82N/A, 0888462709866, Bestellen, Productinformatie, Artikelnummer, Winkelwagen, Plaats en bevestig uw bestelling, €”>
```

Without number:

```
 <meta name="description" lang="nl" content="MacBook Pro 13&quot; 12M i5-3210M/8GB/500GB/DVDRW/10.10 DC i5 2.5GHz/Graphics 4000/US Keyboard, MD101-US-BTO1-A3, , Bestellen, Productinformatie, Artikelnummer, Winkelwagen, Plaats en bevestig uw bestelling, €">
```

Comment: what do you want to target can you explain more?

Comment: Hi Guradio. I want to fetch the string of numbers you can see in the first  meta tags you can see above: 0888462709866 the script I wrote out above fetch everything in the meta. Last part of the puzzle that you amongst others have been kin and helped me figure out :)

Comment: how about the second one what are you trying to get from there?

Comment: there are all kinds of numbers in the meta tag.. how is the script supposed to know which one you're seeking? magic? unfortunately js is not magic. you figure out the logic, explain it to us, and we'll help you with the code.

Comment: the second meta is there to show how it looks when there isn't a number. @PootieTang yes, well this is the problem. As i wrote in the question, My though was to go by index, the order in the string. I showed the meta tag without the number cause it shows that the comma for the number is still there, so I thought that the index order would be the same?

Comment: @JerrySvensson you can work with that split the string using the , if the number will always fall on that index then it is good to go

Comment: He just said the number doesn't always fall in teh same index.

Comment: i'm sorry, js is not magic and the good people of stack overflow are not wizards. there is no possible way to answer this question with the info you have provided.

Comment: @PootieTang the number always fall in the same index - my question was also if the number is empty - would the index stay the same? since the commas where the numbers should be still is there. Then it would be a way to target it.

Comment: oh, i guess i misunderstood. the answer to your question is yes, as long as the number of commas is the same then the index will be the same. you could have easily just tried it and found out for yourself.

Comment: No I couldn't - thats why i asked since I was unsure how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$.each($('meta'),function(){


console.log($(this).attr('content').split(',')[2])

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name='description' lang='nl' content='MacBook 12&quot; 16E M5-6Y54/8GB/512SSD/Space Grey CM5 1.2GHz/HD Graphics 515/US Int. keyboard, MLH82N/A, 0888462709866, Bestellen, Productinformatie, Artikelnummer, Winkelwagen, Plaats en bevestig uw bestelling, €'>

 <meta name='description' lang='nl' content='MacBook Pro 13&quot; 12M i5-3210M/8GB/500GB/DVDRW/10.10 DC i5 2.5GHz/Graphics 4000/US Keyboard, MD101-US-BTO1-A3, , Bestellen, Productinformatie, Artikelnummer, Winkelwagen, Plaats en bevestig uw bestelling, €'>
```

Check this out

Comment: Great as always :D

Comment: @JerrySvensson glad to help mate happy coding :)